# How do I make it so that all executables can run as administrator?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to install Angry Birds on my Windows 7 PC. During installation, it shows an error that it can't be installed becaus i don't have administrator privileges, but I do have those.

When I right click on the installer I see the option to run as administrator and it works.  How can I make the default so that all executables will run as administrator?

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html

Comment: @PerdanaPutra - Talk about useless link.  That does no answer the author's question of "How do I make it so every application by default is run as an administrator?"

Comment: @PerdanaPutra always read the question carefully before answer. The question is about "installing exe files by default as administrator " and not about "run an application "

Comment: Do try disabling UAC once

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it. Installers will usually report requiring elevation anyway. If they don't, Windows will probably ask whether the installation succeeded and give you an option to redo the process with elevation.

For incidental use, take half a second to right-click and run as admin, or type the executable's name in the start menu's search, then hit `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`. Elevate an already running program by clicking its icon in the taskbar holding `Ctrl-Shift`. Change the compatibility properties of a shortcut if a frequently run program always requires administrative rights. Suppress warning messages by turning off UAC if you're doing administrative stuff for a prolonged period, or log in using the Administrator account.

Don't do this by default. It might not answer your question, but it's good advice. As others have rightfully mentioned in caps and bold face, it is a major security issue, and I very much suspect anyone who is even close to capable of handling it, would know how to get elevation by default.

You will suffer all kinds of problems, even if you would never cause one yourself. Automated attacks are common and restricting an application's rights is a very effective way of keeping attackers out. Most computer owners I know who threw this security layer out the door had several botnets competing for CPU time.

Comment: I didn't know about the shortcut to elevate an already running program, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can configure a single application to [always run as Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx).

I don't know of a way to automatically run **all** applications as Administrator and I highly doubt it exists.

Requiring the user to specifically elevate privileges of an application was a major change introduced in Vista (to my knowledge). Reverting this would be a **major** security issue.

That being said, if you really don't care and just want to *do it*, then just [enable the Administrator account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) itself and start using that.

Comment: From what I remember, UAC is what controls elevation and if it's off, everything is automatically run at the highest privilege level the user has (rather than always running as limited by default). And the built-in Administrator account just has UAC always off.

Answer (score 2):

There is no known way to make every application automatically start as an administrator.  You are limited to individually editing the shortcut for each application you want to start as an admin.  However, there is a way to designate individual applications start as an admin for every use that logs into the PC.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1 - Add User To Administrators Group And Remove From Users Group:

1. Log In As Administrator
2. Go To Run ( WinKey + R )
3. Type "control userpasswords2"
4. Select Your Account And Click On "Properties"
5. Select "Group Membership" Tab
6. Select "Administrators"
7. Click OK And OK

---

2 - Disable Approval Mode

1. Log In As Administrator
2. Go To Run ( WinKey + R )
3. Type "secpol.msc"
4. Go To Local Polices > Security Options
5. Find "User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation"
6. Open It Click Disable It And Click Ok.
7. Restart Computer( Very Important Log Off Doesn't Work )

---

Now Every App Will Be Run As Administrator In All Administrator Users